# JQuery, how to combine child selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some HTML like the below, and would like to write a javascript function that returns an object composed of all the `.header` and `span` elements. The below javascript works, but is there a way to combine the headers into a single jQuery selector?

```
<li>
    <div class=".header">
        <span>some stuff</span>
    </div>
</li>
```

```js
_getElements: function() {
    var temp =  $('> li > .header', this.element);
    var temp2 = $('> li > .header > span', this.element);
    var temp3 = temp.add(temp2);
    return temp3;
},
```

Comment: [Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

Comment: Your class (.header) is invalid....classes can't have periods in them.  It would have to be class="header"

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a comma to select multiple things:

```
$('> li > .header, > li > .header > span', this.element);
```

BTW, i've never seen anyone use the direct child selector (`>`) like that, at the beginning of an expression. Does it work?

Comment: Yep, starting a selector with a descendant operator works fine.